# Creating and array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

Hi guys I was wondering if you could shed some light on and idea I was thinking of for my current project. I looking to create say and array of terms, where terms contains two or three values/variables.

Let me try to clear this up as best I can right now.

```
class Term(double e,double c){
      coeff=c;  
      exp=e;
  }

Polynomial poly1[]=[degree]//where degree is some make value of polynomial
poly1[0]= new Term(1,2);
```

i would also like to know if i would be able to call the values of the Term in the poly1 later like:

```
poly1[0].getExp
//where this would give me the exp value of 
//Term in the first entry in the poly1 array
```

sorry if doesn't make much sense. Just let me know and I'll try to clear it up.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Why didn't you try it first before asking?

Comment: "*i would also like to know if i would be able to call the values of the Term in the poly1 later like: `poly1[0].getExp`*" if type of your array (`Polynomial` class) has `getExp` method then you will be able to do it.

Comment: Your example does not use valid Java syntax.

Comment: wasn't sure how to actually implement it or if i was missing something in my logic. Thanks it was sorta half pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basic OOP problem: Polynomial should be parent class of Term (or Polynomial is an interface)

```
interface Polynomial {
   double getExp();
}

class Term implements Polynomial {
   private double coeff;
   private double exp;
   public Term (double e,double c){
      coeff=c;  exp=e;
   }
   @overide
   public double getExp(){
      return exp;
   }
}
```

Comment: What does the use of interface and implements do? Sorry just not familiar with how they work.

Comment: When you call poly1[0].getExp that the poly1 which you define as Polynomial , so the Polynomial should have getExp method
You should read more about http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm

Comment: Hey thanks for the reading material! I'm going to read through it and type some code up but I really appreciate the quick responses everyone. I guess the thought i had seems to exist somewhere already in the java language i just have to figure out how to use it correctly.

Comment: @yelliver - Although the answer was accepted by the poster, I downvoted your answer. In no way should a polynomial extend term - that would not be modelling the domain properly. A polynomial is the sum of many terms - composition is the more appropriate technique here, not inheritance.